# How can I fix a mal-encodede MySQL dump?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, dump

I received a dump from a MySQL database encoded in latin_swedish_1. The dump encoding is UTF-8 but it shows mal-encoded characters. The targeted database in which I'm gonna import the dump has its charset set to utf8_general_ci.

However, I keep the mal-encoded characters when I import the dump.

My question is : how can I fix this dump before importing it ?

Comment: In the first lines of your dump, you should see a `SET NAMES=utf8` statement. Is this the case?

Comment: I have `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;`

Comment: Ok, now are you absolutely sure the dump file is really encoded in UTF8? It could be that the file was altered during transmission (eg.) over FTP. Also, are you importing this dump with the `mysql` command-line client, or with an extrnal tool?

Comment: Yes, the file encoding is really set to "UTF-8".

Comment: I import using mysql command-line client with option "--default-character-set=utf8".

Answer (score 4):

I just realised it: if you can see the malformed characters in a utf8-aware text editor, then the data was already malformed in the source database.

I am assuming you see strings like "Ã©" in your dump, instead of "é". UTF-8 sequences were stored in a latin1 table in your source database. Such sequences were converted again to UTF-8 when generating the dump.

You need to fix your dump by rolling-back one stage of conversion. Under Linux, this can be done easliy:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ISO88591 < broken.sql > fixed.sql
```

Import `fixed.sql`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I tried iconv but I get an error (in french sorry) :
`iconv: séquence d'échappement non permise à la position 10033`

Comment: Could you post an excerpt from your dump where you can see the broken strings (position 10033 is a good candidate)? An image would do if copy/paste doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing special at line 10033 :
`(15613, 37562, 'akismet_history', 'a:4:{s:4:"time";s:13:"1363283704.02";s:7:"message";s:47:"Akismet a revÃ©rifiÃ© et validÃ© ce commentaire";s:5:"event";s:9:"check-ham";s:4:"user";s:0:"";}'),`

Comment: The position is in byte, not in line. Try this: `head -c 10043 dump.sql |tail -c 20`. I am afraid your dump file is more broken than I thought... Let me guess, this is what you see: � right?

Comment: In the fixed.sql file, I can get the characters where iconv crashed. I tried to fix them one by one manually but there are too many of them.

Comment: I am sorry, you will need some byte-level scripting to fix your dump. "�" are ISO-8859-1 characters interpreted as UTF-8 (i.e. the exact opposite problem of "Ã©"). 1. Detect all characters like "�" (for example, by calling `iconv`). 2. Replace them by their twice-UTF-8-encoded counterpart (eg. "Ã©"). 3. Convert the resulting file as advised in my answer (`-f utf8 -t ISO88591`). 4. Hope for the best. Good luck!

Comment: Something just crossed my mind. Perhaps the text was supposed to be CP1252 (a.k.a Windows-1252). Try converting you (unmodified) dump with `iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252`. Might work, who knows. Also try with other encodigs like `iso855915`.

Comment: Hello, I do not have "�" but UTF-8 errors like "Ã©". "iconv" does not do the trick in the fixed part before crashing. I still have "Ã©" in the dump. In fact, I stop fixing this file since I've asked for a new cleanr dump. Thanks for your help.